# Getting distant belongsToMany through belongsToMany

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm trying to grab a distant relationship and it isn't working. I've tried doing a `hasManyThrough` but that doesn't appear to work for `belongsToMany` relationships. It was throwing a query error.

Here are my migrations:

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });


    Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('role_id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
    });

    Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('group');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('permission_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('permission_id');
        $table->integer('role_id');
    });
```

Here are my models:

```
class User extends AuthUser
{
    //

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }
}

class Role extends Model
{
    //

    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Permission');
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);
Log::info($user->roles->permissions);
```

This gives me a `Property [permissions] does not exist on this collection instance.` error.

How do I grab the users permissions through their roles?

**EDIT:**

I've come up with this ugly solution to what I'm trying to do:

```
if (auth()->check()) {
    if (auth()->user()->roles->contains('name', 'Admin')) {
        Gate::before(function () {
            return true;
        });
    }
    else {
        $permissions = [];

        foreach (auth()->user()->roles as $role) {
            $permissions = array_merge($permissions, $role->permissions->pluck('name')->all());
        }

        foreach (array_unique($permissions) as $permission) {
            Gate::define($permission, function () {
                return true;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

How can I improve this?

Comment: user & roles have many-to-many relationship ?

Comment: what is your relationship like? is it one user has many roles and those roles have many permissions?

Comment: @ImmortalDude Yes exactly.

Comment: @kjdion84 I think hasMany can't be used for many-to-many relationship as it uses foreign keys in models to retrieve relationship via intermediate one-to-many relationship.

Comment: Well, i would suggest going over the laravel eloquent documentation once more because it seems you missed this line `Eloquent determines the foreign key of the relationship based on the model name.` i.e. you need to use foreign keys

Comment: Right, it automatically looks for a column such as `user_id` based on the model name being `User`. It has nothing to do with foreign keys being declared in the schema.

Answer (score 1):

You should eager load those relationships like this:

```
$user = User::with(['roles', 'roles.permissions'])->where('id', 1)->first();
```

This will give you an array of roles, and each role with their respective permissions.

```
Permission::whereHas('role', function($query) use ($user_id) {
    return $query->whereHas('user_id', $user_id);
});
```

The idea in the above query is that when you want the many to many of a distant relationship, `you work backwards`.

Comment: Can you look at the OP. I showed some example code in the edit of what I'm trying to do. I'm basically trying to refactor the code now so it is less shitty. Any tips?

Comment: Can you also provide the reasoning behind it? As your example probably works, but let the OP understand why his reasoning fails, and why aggregation doesn't work on many-to-many to many-to-many relations :P

Answer (score 0):

change $user=App\USER->find(1);

to this 
$user= App\User::find(1);

try this will work for you

Comment: There was a typo in my question. It already was ` App\User::find(1)`. It does not work.

Answer (score 0):

you have not set foreign key in migration
$table->foreign('role_id)->references('id')->on('roles');

Same define for users

Comment: Foreign keys do not resolve the issue. Relationships work without foreign keys being set. I also added foreign keys and tried it and the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

It gave you `Property [permissions] does not exist on this collection instance.` error because: `$user->roles` returns a collection of roles while `permissions` in your model Role is for a single model only ..

Basically you have to `foreach($user->roles as $role)` before you can use `$role->permissions`

but here's a sample where you don't have to foreach to get a permission depending on a role ..

`auth()->user()->roles->where('name','=','Administrator')->permissions;`

and that would be returning an array/collection of permissions of an administrator ..